# Existence of the close in norm matrix.

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Assume we have $\dot{x} = A(t) x$. Let's consider a small fluctuation of the system $\dot{y} = [A(t) + Q(t)] y$. Let's denote by $X(t,s) = X(t) X^{-1}(s)$ - Cauchy operator, where $X(t)$ is fundamental matrix.

Assume also that $A(t)$ is upper-triangular and $\|\|_2$ be the norm. We want to determine, if there is a non-zero matrix $Q(t) \in M_n:$ $\|X_{A+Q}(t,s)\|_2 - \|X_A(t,s)\|_2 < \epsilon$ and $\sup_t\|Q(t)\|_2 < \epsilon$. So I'm interested in if for any operator matrix $A(t)$ we can find small (w.r.t. norm) $Q(t)$ for which norm of Cauchy operator is almost the same (w.r.t. the norm).

Comment: $Q(t) = 0$ seems to be a solution to your problem, as it is stated now.

Comment: @SolubleFish i've edited. Thanks for the note!